# Oracle APEX Interactive Report filter

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive report with a column that displays an icon using HTML. The icon is a check mark to indicate if the specific fund is a scholarship or not. When filtering on that column to show only rows with the check mark the filter status shows "Sholarship = HTML CODE" instead of "Scholarship = CHECKMARK"

Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296736/oracle-apex-19-x-external-url-based-on-items-value

Comment: I already have escape special characters unselected

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your own SQL query in the filter section of the Particular Column.